# MySQL check if row with category exists

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, where-in

I'm using the Haversine formula with this query and it works until. The goal is to check if each row has certain categories in an value of $deflin which looks like $deflin = category1, category2, category3. The results will show rows within 50km and if it contains any of the categories defined by $deflin. Not sure how to approach this either with WHERE IN or LIKE. Any help is appreciated.

MySQL for query

```
$awaka = "SELECT *,
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians(job_latitude) ) *   
cos(radians(?) - radians(job_longitude) ) + sin( radians(?) ) *   
sin( radians(job_latitude) ) ) ) AS distance FROM job, users   
WHERE job.listee_id = users.user_id AND job.job_category LIKE ?   
HAVING distance < 50";

$result = $this->db->query($awaka, array($conlat, $conlong, $conlat, $deflin));
```

Comment: You could do `job.job_category IN ('category1','category2','category3')` this would return rows that have a `job_category` which is either of category1, category2 or category3

Comment: If  `job_category` is an id you would have to change your query to something like `job.job_category IN ($deflin)`. Notice that you **don't** wan't to use `LIKE` since this operator searches for patterns within a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you like to use the `LIKE` operator since it only searches for patterns within a column and you only wan't to return rows that **really** has one of your categories. Instead you should use an `IN` clause to check if a job has one of your categories:

```
// contains the id for each category
$categories = array(1, 4, 5, 6);
$deflin = implode(',', $categories);

// if job_category is a text column you could do like this instead
$categories = array('category1', 'category2', 'category3');
$deflin = implode(',', $categories);    

$awaka = "SELECT *,
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians(job_latitude) ) *   
cos(radians(?) - radians(job_longitude) ) + sin( radians(?) ) *   
sin( radians(job_latitude) ) ) ) AS distance FROM job, users   
WHERE job.listee_id = users.user_id AND job.job_category IN ($deflin)   
HAVING distance < 50";
```

Comment: Just used this and tweaked it. It works well now. Thanks for the help :).